# Apple Store distribution - iOs 6-7 App : updates and maintenance from different mac

Tags: ios, app-store

I'am currently developing an app for a company, they applied to the developer program and gave me credentials to publish to the store.

I have cleared my mind about the publishing chain but I am a bit confused about app maintenance/updates here's my question:

let's say that the app maintenance/updates are managed by another person from now on ( using a different mac ).

What should I do ( I published to the store from my mac ) in order to let this person do its job?.

thank you.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share you private key that was generated when you created certificate on Apple Dev Portal to the other person. You can find them in "Keychain Access". Other person can import that key in their Keychain Access App and they can use any Provisioning Profile associated with that certificate to maintain app and updates.

Screenshot where you can find certificates:
[image]

Comment: Seems an acceptable way, I'll probably end up using this one, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does not matter from which Mac you did it first. If he is connected to the same team and has the provisioning profiles and so on then that should be no problem.

Do you upload the binary with the ApplicationLoader apple provides?

Comment: I uploaded the app using the "Deliver" option in xCode 5.1.1 .